# What is the numeric type equivalent in KnexJS (Postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I am creating a table using [Knex.JS](http://knexjs.org/), and the table has a column for a currency value.

For example, here is the column `amount`:

```
knex.schema.createTable('payment', function(table) {
  table.increments();
  table.float('amount');
})
```

Currently, I am using the `float` type, but I'd like to use the `numeric` type. What is the equivalent of the [numeric](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) type in Knex.JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For currency `decimal` is best match, so your code may look like:

```
knex.schema.createTable('payment', function(table) {
  table.increments();
  table.decimal('amount',14,2); // e.g. 14 positions, 2 for the cents
});
```

see http://knexjs.org/#Schema-decimal

Comment: I was confused about this as well. From the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-numeric.html): "The types `decimal` and `numeric` are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard."